# Fill/Border color in LibreOffice's Data Ranges for bar graph

Tags: libreoffice-calc

> [image: Border color]

What kind of value is it expecting to be in these cells?  I've tried html hex codes, the `COLOR()` function, HTML color names, etc.  None seem to do anything.

Comment: Does each bar need to have a different border color, or can they all have the same color, for example black?  Most charts I have seen use different fill colors rather than different border colors.

Comment: @JimK  Either.  I've changed the title

Answer (score 4):

`Fill Color` works with [COLOR](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/COLOR_function) values, so presumably `Border Color` would expect the same.

However AFAICT, `Border Color` from data ranges does not seem to be implemented yet.

Instead, the border color can be changed manually, either on a particular bar or on all bars.  To do this, double-click on the bars (or right click -> Format Data Series), then under the Borders tab, choose a color.

**A little more detail** - In order for `Fill Color` to work, the Data Series Area must be formatted to use a Color, which is black by default.  Changing the Area to None will cause the `Fill Color` Data Series to be ignored.  Applying similar logic, I set the border color to black, which did display a border, but the `Border Color` Data Series still did not have any effect.

**EDIT**

For an example of using a `Fill Color` range, start with an empty spreadsheet and enter the following.

```
X   Y               bar color
~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2   =POWER(A2,2)   =COLOR(255,0,0)
3   =POWER(A3,2)   =COLOR(0,255,0)
4   =POWER(A4,2)   =COLOR(0,0,255)
```

Then select A1 to B4 and insert a Bar Chart.  Set the `Fill Color` range for Y to `$Sheet1.$C$2:$C4` and press Finish.  The result:

[image: colored bars]